# Is there a bad way to read and write to a hard drive?

Tags: winapi, hard-drive

I am writing a disk utility for windows that just uses CreateFile to open physical drives and read and write to them.
I am currently trying to implement a testing feature that will thoroughly test a drive for consistency. I wrote a function that would open a drive for read and write, write 10meg of data (in one call to WriteFile) seek back to the start of where that 10meg was written (using SetFilePointer) then read it back (also in one call to ReadFile) test that the read matches the written, then proceed to the next 10meg etc
The problem is that on the two (old) hard drives I have tried this on, the process eventually fails after about 5mins (its going fine then the drive will just disconnect from the system, or spaz out in general requiring a reboot)
Both these drives pass WD Diag tests.

*Im wondering if it is possible to just 'stress' a drive beyond designed operational limits.*

**So my question is this**:  Should you be able to perform any combination of read, write, seek operations on a drive in good heath, without it failing?  (I know you have to read/write in multiples of 512, and obviously all drives have a limited life and would fail eventually, but surely should be able to go at least a few hours)

Comment: I am suspicious of all the hardware involved - not just the hard drives, including the old motherboard and PCI SATA card the drives are plugged into, but that's a separate question for another time.

Comment: Your hardware is defective. Reading and writing some data should absolutely not cause system instability.

Comment: Or perhaps your code is defective.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the symptoms?  Does your application receive error codes (and if so, which ones) or does Windows complain to the user about the drive?  Did the drive have a file system on it before you started overwriting it?